# Can't delete server from DPM console

Tags: scdpm

I made a mistake installing a DPM agent on one of my servers. I installed it as if it were on an untrusted domain, using the `-isNonDomainServer` option. This succeeded, even though the server was the domain controller for the domain in question.

The DPM server failed to connect to the agent. I tried using SetDpmServer with just the DPM server name, that fails with error code `0x80004005`.

So now I have a domain computer listed as (untrusted) in my DPM console, but I can't find a way to delete it or to reconfigure the agent to be on a trusted domain. Whatever I try gives an error.

How can I just delete this computer from DPM and start over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the Agent is already installed on the server you want to protect:

Run on the server with the agent `setdpmserver -DPMServerName dpm.server.name.com`
On the DPM server, under management, Install Agent, Attach, domain computer, credentials...

No reinstalling needed. No need to remove the server from the DPM Console.

<sub>Syntax and properly working DNS are absolutely essential for DPM to work correctly. 0x80004005 means that the Agent computer could not resolve the name you provided for the DPM server. You should be providing the FQDN for the DPM server, not the NetBIOS name.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Chris, good point about the FQDN being necessary, I discovered that the hard way. But I already tried your suggestion as mentioned above and it didn't work. Or at least it appeared not to. I went and did something else for an hour and came back, and the agent/server had disappeared from the DPM console. So I reconnected the agent and all working now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax for removing the stale DPM agent record:

```
Remove-ProductionServer.ps1 'DPM Server Name' 'Protected Server Name'
```

Comment: Useful in other situations, not necessary in this case.